# Output doesn't work properly when i try to get his value on vb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, adodb

This is my first question

```
alter proc InsertarVentas
    @ban int output
as
    declare @fecha date
    set @fecha = GETDATE()
begin 
    insert into Ventas (tipoven, fecha) 
    values ('contado', @fecha)

    insert into BANPAC.dbo.Ventas (tipoven, fecha) 
    values ('contado', @fecha)

    select @ban = scope_identity()

    print (@ban)
end
```

I am trying to use this stored procedure to obtain the value of the id of the last insert but it doesn't work

And this is the code from vb:

```
Sub InsertarNuevaVenta()
        comando = New ADODB.Command
        With comando
            .CommandText = "InsertarVentas"
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("0", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 1, "H"))
            .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput,, 0))
            .ActiveConnection = Conexion_vta
            .Execute()
            ban.Value = .Parameters(1).Value
            MessageBox.Show(ban.Value.ToString)
        End With
        Vta_txt_clave_venta.Text = ban.Value.ToString
    End Sub
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the proc and remove `PRINT`. In VB.NET, you should used SqlClient instead of ADODB.

Comment: i know that i should be using sqlClient but the teacher wants it with adodb, and the print its only to see if the scope_identity() works and it does but not in the vb

Comment: thank you so much it works, you saved my life

Comment: Alternative way to get correct last id would be [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the proc after the `AS` and remove `PRINT`. In VB.NET, you should used SqlClient instead of ADODB.

This works perfectly for me :D Thanks to Dan Guzman